# Copying data from a dropdown menu to a seperate sheet as a report using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, dropdown

Complete beginner with VBA and I think I'm doing something majorly wrong.

So context;

Creating a user friendly sheet to do checks on items etc. To keep it as simple as possible for other people I've decided to use drop down menus to input the majority of the data and tick boxes to say when the check has been done.

From here I want to add a big old button that will transfer the data from the cells, dropdown menu and tick boxes to another sheet or workbook.

I would also need the sheet or workbook to place the date the checks were done and create a new line with the information. So that I can look at a single sheet and see the wear and tear on the equipment in one form. (layout of this can be sorted out after wards just how to get it to go to a blank line etc.)
And finally to save the document.

drop down information is linked from another sheet within the workbook.

Now I've tried some code to work it out myself and it either doesn't copy the data as the cell is blank (drop down menus) or it just shoots up an error on the VBA page.

Could anyone assist in helping me work this code out? Even if its just the command syntax's that I would need to use.

Thanks in advance

Peter

Comment: Edit your question to include the code you have tried so far :)

Comment: Please show some code that you tried and which errors at which line you got. We can't pull this up from scratch for you.